# How to save results (and recall them when needed) of a simulation in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I started  (based on the idea shown in this model an actuarial project in Python in which I want to simulate, based on a set of inputs and adding (as done here: https://github.com/Saurabh0503/Financial-modelling-and-valuationn/blob/main/Dynamic%20Salary%20Retirement%20Model%20Internal%20Randomness.ipynb) some degree of internal randomness, how much it will take for an individual to retire, with a certain amount of wealth and a certain amount of annual salary and by submitting a certain annual payment (calculated as the desired cash divided by the years that will be necessary to retire). In my model's variation, the user can define his/her own parameters, making the model more flexible and user friendly; and there is a function that calculates the desired retirement cash based on individual's propensity both to save and spend.

The problem is that since I want to summarize (by taking the mean, max, min and std. deviation of wealth, salary and years to retirement) the output I obtain from the model, I have to save results (and to recall them) when I need to do so; but I don't have idea of what to do in order to accomplish this task.

I tried this solution, consisting in saving the simultation's output in a pandas dataframe. In particular I wrote that function:

```
def get_salary_wealth_year_case_df(data):
    all_ytrs = []
    salary = []
    wealth = []
    annual_payments = []
    for i in range(data.n_iter):
        ytr = years_to_retirement(data, print_output=False)
        sal = salary_at_year(data, year, case, print_output=False)
        wlt = wealth_at_year(data, year, prior_wealth, case, print_output=False)
        pmt = annual_pmts_case_df(wealth_at_year, year, case, print_output=False)
        all_ytrs.append(ytr)
        salary.append(sal)
        annual_payments.append(pmt)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['Years to Retirement'] = all_ytrs
    df['Salary'] = sal
    df['Wealth'] = wlt
    df['Annual Payments'] = pmt
    return df
```

I need a feedback about what I'm doing. Am I doing it right? If so, are there more efficient ways to do so? If not, what should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You didn't "save" them anywhere per se. Dataframe is not saved to the HDD by default. You need to save it to CSV or some other file

Answer (score 0):

Given the inputs used for the function, I'm assuming your code (as it is) will do just fine in terms of computation speed.

As suggested, you can add a saving option to your function so the results that are being returned are stored in a .csv file.

```
def get_salary_wealth_year_case_df(data, path):
    all_ytrs = []
    salary = []
    wealth = []
    annual_payments = []
    for i in range(data.n_iter):
        ytr = years_to_retirement(data, print_output=False)
        sal = salary_at_year(data, year, case, print_output=False)
        wlt = wealth_at_year(data, year, prior_wealth, case, print_output=False)
        pmt = annual_pmts_case_df(wealth_at_year, year, case, print_output=False)
        all_ytrs.append(ytr)
        salary.append(sal)
        annual_payments.append(pmt)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['Years to Retirement'] = all_ytrs
    df['Salary'] = sal
    df['Wealth'] = wlt
    df['Annual Payments'] = pmt

    # Save the dataframe to a given path inside your workspace
    df.to_csv(path, header=False)

    return df
```

After saving, returning the object might be optional. This depends on if you are going to use this dataframe on your code moving forward.

Comment: Make sure to upvote my answer and validate it! just started answering questions over here :)

Comment: Ahahahahah don't worry. Actually the forum gives me this message "You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."; but trust me: your help has been very appreciated!